# not able to change the confirmation email template in Self hosted supabase

Tags: supabase

I was trying to change the confirmation email template of the self-hosted supabase on my local machine but was not able to.

I created an email template and made it available at `http://localhost:3000/templates/email/confirm.html` and added the below config on the .env file
`MAILER_TEMPLATES_CONFIRMATION="http://localhost:3000/templates/email/confirm.html"`

and also added to the `docker-compose.yml` file as below

`GOTRUE_MAILER_TEMPLATES_CONFIRMATION: ${MAILER_TEMPLATES_CONFIRMATION}`

and restarted the docker, but when I did the signup, it still uses the default confirmation email template,

can anybody tell me what I am missing here?